# Ionic 4 Google Map set Traffic Layer

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to add in Traffic Layer into my google maps. It seem like I am not able to get the traffic Layer. Please Help, thanks in advance.

```
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.maps = new google.maps.Map (
      this.mapElement.nativeElement,
      {
        center: { lat: 3.068352 , lng:101.602965 },
        zoom: 14,
        styles: [{
          featureType: 'poi',
          stylers: [{ visibility: 'on'}]
        }, {
          featureType: 'transit.station.bus',
          stylers: [{ visibility: 'on'}]
        }, {
          featureType: 'transit.station.rail',
          stylers: [{ visibility: 'on'}]
        }],
      }

this.maps.trafficLayer = new google.maps.trafficLayer(),
this.trafficLayer.setMap(this.maps);

);
```

Comment: TrafficLayer object is case sensitive. Could you please try changing "google.maps.trafficLayer()" to "google.maps.TrafficLayer()" and let me know if the issue still happening?

Comment: I have tried 

      this.maps.trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer(),
      this.trafficLayer.setMap(this.maps)

it still doesn't show up